# Conveying "rough diamond" talking about a person

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, anglicismes

> Joe is not that bad, you know! Deep down, he’s really kind even though he seems to lack good manners at times. He’s a rough diamond (i.e. a person who is generally of good character but lacks manners, education, or style).

> Joe n'est pas si mal, tu sais ! Au fond, il est vraiment gentil même s'il semble parfois manquer de bonnes manières. C'est un diamant brut.

Diamand brut does not sound natural at all to my ears. What are some idiomatic ways to convey this meaning of 'rough diamond'?

Comment: *Diamond in the rough* is a more common expression, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je n'y aurais jamais songé et le mérite revient entièrement à [*Larousse en ligne anglais-français*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/rough_diamond/608466), qui découple l'épithète du nom en deux éléments distincts réunis par une opposition avec la conjonction *mais* :

> **Il est bourru mais il a un cœur d'or.** [ *Larousse en ligne* ]

[On trouve ça](https://www.google.com/search?q=bourru%20mais%20a%20un%20coeur%20d%27or&tbm=bks) en effet.

---

*He's a diamond in the rough* (especially US) : **Il a un cœur d'or sous ses dehors frustes.** [ [*Larousse en ligne*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/diamond/575380) ]

Comment: Au choix, selon que l'on parle de la personne ou de son comportement https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fruste - https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bourru